# ts narrowing with getter

Tags: typescript, narrowing

I , am actually look for a cheap solution to allow ts **narrowing** with a getter or string compare instead of a `instanceAB instanceof instanceA` to get narrowing.

Is ts have some solution for this?

```
export class Token {
   type:'TokenContainer'|'TokenPrimitive'|null = null;
   get isContainer(){
      return this.type === 'TokenContainer'
   }
      get isPrimitive(){
       return this.type === 'TokenPrimitive' 
   }
    foo0(){}
}

export class TokenContainer extends Token {
   type:'TokenContainer' = 'TokenContainer';
   foo1(){}
   
}

export class TokenPrimitive extends Token {
    type:'TokenPrimitive' = 'TokenPrimitive'
     foo2(){}
}


let test!:Token;
// is possible to make this work ?.
if(test.isContainer){
   test.foo1()
}
// is possible to make this work ?
if(test.type === 'TokenContainer' ){
   test.foo1()
}

// instead of this
if(test instanceof TokenContainer ){
   test.foo1()
}
```

**link**: [tsPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFFMA8AcHsCcAuACAxgGwIYGdvICqwDW4AdsgN6jI2ICe04AXAOSEmkDCspimAlqXDwWAHzbEyABXj8Atv0T8AbuDGkArunTIAvMk3aA3NRoBzcCn7ZuvAUPgAKAJRUQND8niWN8cogALawA6ekY9XX0JDls%20QWEWU2QAXySPCytsGXlFFXAXN08Pb0RffyDsUIZwCKj2aVkFJVUWZCTU9w8AM1hYAAYCjo6IGAQUDBw8eq4eOIdkKEQyABMpyXJC2mrWadj7BL1kaLI9%20JETTuQe2ABGQaTQYZAoOCQ0LFwCdeymvIXIJakVZfDiUNJhZjHUg-XItQ5QmHNNRpK69ABM9xAT1A6EsyCW2EQAEImNMLgB6cmAXg3AEf7yGsyDguH4ACNcfjYMg5JgSPiKsgAO4IIjIAD8wVA-C6jgJiGC1lODlcSVlwWud2cj1AlNp9LwTOwrPZiE53N5gQZQvgItFkulqohtSOu1m%20xEyGVl1V6pcWrAIB1gBZd%20mkQngTDLZCwLp86x2mXgQkhwmYUiocDRkEnV1nD2bfGJuU%20zVYoA)

Comment: Take a look at [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAVABW) meet your needs?  If so I will write up an answer.  If not, please elaborate on the failing use cases, preferably by [edit]ing your code example.

Comment: @jcalz ho sorry i read by mistake wrong thing :) yes your approche give me good tips , thanks a lot, i will test deeper

Comment: @jcalz ok yes it work good on my side, approved :) thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are not looking to refactor your code so as to change the runtime behavior or even the emitted JavaScript.  That is, the changes I will make to your code only affect the TypeScript type checker.

---

Property getters in TypeScript behave essentially the same as regular properties when it comes to narrowing.  There is a suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#43368](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43368) to allow property getters to act as [user defined type guard functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), but currently there is no such facility in the language.  So if you want to get the type checker behavior you want, we'll have to do it in a way that would also work if `isContainer` and `isPrimitive` were just normal properties.

---

That means both your `isContainer`/`isPrimitive` checks as well as your `type` check need to act as a type guard on the type of the `test` object.  In TypeScript, the only way a property check can act as a type guard on the type of the containing object is if the object's type is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) and the property is a discriminant of that union.

The `Token` type is not a discriminated union.  It's not even a union at all; it's just a class instance interface.  So if `test` is [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) as `Token`, then what you want is not possible.  The first step toward enabling this, then, is to annotate `test` as a union type:

```
type SomeToken = TokenContainer | TokenPrimitive;            
declare let test: SomeToken;
```

And we now have to ensure that `SomeToken` is a discriminated union with `isContainer`, `isPrimitive`, and `type` being discriminant properties.

---

Well, the `type` property is already a discriminant.  The `TokenContainer` and `TokenPrimitive` both have a `type` property whose type is a distinct string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html).  So that check will immediately work:

```
if (test.type === 'TokenContainer') {
   test.foo1() // okay
} else {
   test.foo2() // okay
}
```

---

The story is different for `isContainer` and `isPrimitive`.  They are only declared on the `Token` superclass and are inherited by the subclasses. If you declare them explicitly on the subclasses, of appropriate hardcoded boolean literal types, this will start to work.  But we don't want to make any runtime changes by explicitly overriding them, so you instead need to do something like [the `declare` property modifier in the subclasses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier), which unfortunately are not legal when the parent property is a getter; see [microsoft/TypeScript#40220](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40220), so the current workaround is to use (yuck) [a `//@ts-ignore` comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#suppress-errors-in-ts-files-using--ts-ignore-comments):

```
export class TokenContainer extends Token {
   type: 'TokenContainer' = 'TokenContainer';
   //@ts-ignore
   declare readonly isContainer: true;
   //@ts-ignore
   declare readonly isPrimitive: false;
   foo1() { }
}

export class TokenPrimitive extends Token {
   type: 'TokenPrimitive' = 'TokenPrimitive'
   //@ts-ignore
   declare readonly isContainer: false;
   //@ts-ignore
   declare readonly isPrimitive: true;
   foo2() { }
}
```

You can verify that this works:

```
if (test.isContainer) {
   test.foo1() // okay
} else {
   test.foo2() // okay
}
```

But I don't recommend this until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#40220 is implemented.

---

Instead you could make the parent class property type conditional depending on the type of the implementing subclass as represented by [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types).  That is, you leave `TokenContainer` and `TokenPrimitive` alone, but [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the getters return something dependent on the actual subclass type:

```
export class Token {
   type: 'TokenContainer' | 'TokenPrimitive' | null = null;
   get isContainer() {
      return (this.type === 'TokenContainer') as 
        this extends TokenContainer ? true : false
   }
   get isPrimitive() {
      return (this.type === 'TokenPrimitive') as 
        this extends TokenPrimitive ? true : false
   }
   foo0() { }
}
```

The types like `this extends TokenContainer ? true : false` are more or less unresolved [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types inside the class implementations, but when you use instances of the subclasses, they will resolve to either `true` or `false`.  And then this will also work:

```
if (test.isContainer) {
   test.foo1() // okay
} else {
   test.foo2() // okay
}
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBRAHjANgS3tgLgMoCuARvJiFFACIQUgBOI+2A9sEgN4CwAUPyRCIGNo3xIG1JABU2AawidefIWqT4AnjAgAuJAHI5i4AGEO+ENmARGBpAB9DxpQAVG2MAWwA3CPadgYkxMJABeJCCQgG5BdSQAcwgJbChzYEtrWwAKAEpuOPihRmTiRk5s-AALVIA6LR1wsIijBSV0zJs7XMK1AF9eoSSUqHdPbz88gtUi4tLypEqaqHrtZGaWl2Axr1Y-Ax6Z9QGjtQAzNjYABimuJBP+-iejkRgxCSkoWTazCysupAifBKAAmXy20yKDT0zh+HX+tnsmzhfyydlipyEAHosQABfBQAC02ASwDEEEGSBB9EoJSQJRAII4mE0SFS8LR+nwjGIEAxRRx+KJJLJJUp1IYdIZTOALLZow8u18MLOIEwUD5zyKFzYAEZbvctUIToVXu9JJRpFsdhNkEDQeCftNKdD9K0TDa9v5wrCPYrbQZKYKCcTSeTxTSmMhpczWezUV19Kr1ZrMUhg8Kw2K0xLadGIIzY-LPcquTzU5SdQAmA0PY1GjRrJCENiQCERLYcgFOa3+r0Ywq5qNITDJDTQfD6Fttn4Do7YM6LYFQfC1eMZBGMfIqKET2o6-X5HFIBQgTSFPqAlOQ+LL1fVqbH0-no4m+eLyp76FNZEmLuI7cXT3A88gvK8NRvdQ733S4a0OR4BD4N9+FASBYAQZASB0RhTEtNIOBBbwODVGQmxUU1RHEC0qEdExILUV1fXaBNEUcJjtj7ZUAkiYJQgiKJMH5eJhnlf9GFuSk1BKfAygqao6m-DZ2LEg4kCoDRlkBNBgWAMFvj-FjGCQAB+DRyyQJM1Q1Sk63UETUhLSZALTKT5jk5ZVkaJT3TcTj9nydT5K+e1dNo3zxi9EyzN5CykGTay01s85LhubdDVfZ4KLeKjPn05iNzRLSdL0iEd1vNY3U7QykWU6qhPUEC0rfBCsvNXLewi5UiodPLlBdCr2Mc71f3CpV9krWDawvBtv2nCB216sS2I6saKyOIc6VHCQ7ynVt5tnBsFyXPd106WxnN3FcYL1R8sRPeQzzAiBrzKqDgMmo87ufabELUI7PyuxTmlqgqulU16GPem74ONcDkAhoRoIfGH0v4PogA)

Comment: This was very informative ! thanks a lot to share your time like this :)